# Pulled Windows 10 Surface 3 out of storage... now what?

Tags: windows-10, certificate, microsoft-surface

I just pulled a Surface 3 out of storage. I haven't used it in about a year and I can't visit any websites without running into "invalid certificate" errors. Last time I used the tablet, it worked fine.

Where do I begin fixing this?

Comment: Check your date and time, they have likely been reset where the battery ran out completely. This would cause SSL certificate errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the tablet hasn't been used for many months then the battery and CMOS battery will have lost charge so your computer is not keeping the system date/time which is crucial for your browser to determine whether a certificate has expired or not.

Comment: Whelp, I totally assumed that connecting it to the Internet would cause it to update the date/time. How wrong I was. It's updating now.